# Auto-delegation to a val in a Scala method

Tags: scala, dsl

I'm writing ScalaTest FeatureSpec's for a Wicket app. I have a wicketTester value, that I keep on having to call methods on, viz:

```
scenario("No username and password") {
  val wicketTester = new WicketTester(app)
  given("user visits Admin home page")
  wicketTester.startPage(classOf[AdminHomePage])

  then("signin page is displayed")
  val login = wicketTester.newFormTester("signInPanel:signInForm")
  wicketTester.assertRenderedPage(classOf[SignInPage])
  ...
  when("correct username and password are entered")
  ...
  then("no login and error is displayed")
  wicketTester.assertRenderedPage(classOf[SignInPage])
  wicketTester.assertErrorMessages(Array("Field 'password' is required."))
```

Now all these refs to wicketTester are getting me down, so I want to remove them, aiming for DSL nirvana...

```
scenario("No username and password") {
  val wicketTester = new WicketTester(app)
  given("user visits Admin home page")
  startPage(classOf[AdminHomePage])

  then("signin page is displayed")
  val login = wicketTester.newFormTester("signInPanel:signInForm")
  assertRenderedPage(classOf[SignInPage])...
```

Is there any way to make the methods on a local appear as if they are methods on my class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try an import?

```
scenario("No username and password") {
   val wicketTester = new WicketTester(app)
   import wicketTester._    // import wicketTester's members into scope
   given("user visits Admin home page")
   startPage(classOf[AdminHomePage])

   then("signin page is displayed")
   val login = wicketTester.newFormTester("signInPanel:signInForm")
   assertRenderedPage(classOf[SignInPage])...  
}
```

Comment: You beauty! I'd seen that done somewhere recently and thought that it would come in handy, but obviously reading isn't enough to internalize - I actually have to bang my head against the compiler!